# How to obtain TCPDump Test Data

Tags: tcpdump

First time poster, long time reader.  Honestly pretty terrified of posting.

I'm writing a TCPDump trace analyzer for a class in school.  Pretty simple, analyze Hex-Formatted traces from the Unix TCPDump application.  Typically we run TCPDump on the pcap output to obtain our program input as follows:

```
tcpdump -nn -X -r inputfile.dmp > outputfile.trace
```

We've got it doing just about everything it needs to with the exception of IP options and TCP options.  We've got an awful lot of code written for a subset of IP options that are easily implementable, but are kind of clueless about how to get meaningful test data that reflects a real, non-contrived/constructed trace.  We tried manually creating packets with options we'd like to test, and that works fairly well, but it doesn't necessarily reflect what we, or future users, might actually input.

Can anyone give some suggestions on how to go about getting some actual test data?

The IP Options we're looking at are: End-of-Option, No-Option, Strict Source Route, Loose Source Route, Record Route, Security, Extended Security and Timestamp.

The TCP Options we're looking at are: End-of-Option, No-Option, MSS, WSCALE, SACK-Permitted, SACK, TSOPT.

So far, most of the google searches I've done have resulted in fruitless results.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Wireshark wiki has quite a few and also contains links to other sources - http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Sample_Captures.

HTH!

Comment: ...not all of which are pcap or pcap-ng files, so not all of them will be readable by tcpdump.

Comment: Just a warning in case the original poster didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

[pcapr](http://www.pcapr.net/home) has a bunch of captures on it.  You'll have to open an account to download captures.